# Rails - association to find both parents and grandparents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume I have these models

```
class User
    has_many: groups
    has_many: teams, :as => :user
end

class Group
    has_many: users
    has_many: teams, :as => :user
end

class Team
end
```

Essentially

- `User` can be added to `Group` or `Team`
- `Group` can be added to `Team`

For this code,

```
User.first.teams
```

I want to get all `Team` that the first `User` belongs to, either directly added to the team or added to the `Team` through a `Group`.

I could have added a new method, or association extension to get all transitive teams, but I want `user.teams` to work because `Group` model is newly added, and there are tons of code already using `user.teams`.

I have also tried adding an instance method named `teams` in `User` model, which returns the transitive teams as relation object, so that scopes continue to work. However, if the scope uses anything from a linked table, it has trouble finding columns on the linked tables.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a user_id on Team?  or is there a join model?

Comment: You are creating a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Group` you should probably be using [has many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working with a proper hack job.

Your setup is the perfect candidate for [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), or [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association); both representing `many-to-many` relationships...

---

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :teams #-> requires a users_teams table
end

#app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users  
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups #-> requires a groups_teams table
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

... this way, your teams will be a part of a "group", which would be accessed by `@user.teams.first.groups` or similar.

--

If you were Microsoft, you may say...

```
The Internet Services *group* has the Microsoft Edge *team*

@group = Group.find_by        name: "Internet Services"
@team  = @group.teams.find_by name: "Microsoft Edge"
@users = @team.users
```

If you were a user, you'd be able to use:

```
@user = User.find x
@team = User.teams.find y
@group = @team.groups.find z
```

---

Your pattern is hacky because you're interchanging `groups` and `teams`.

Ruby is [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming); Rails is object orientated.

If a `User` object belongs to a team, that is one thing.

If that same object can then belong to another object, you have to question the scope of the other object. In short; why can a user be part of a group *and* team?